# How do I validate multiple patterns?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validation

I have a single form element that sends its value to a PHP script. This value needs to be validated and it there are 5 different sets that it can be grouped to,

```
x stands for digits 0-9
```

> Set 1: ABxxTXxx
>
> Set 2: ABxxTXAxxx
>
> Set 3: ABCxxx
>
> Set 4: Axxx
>
> Set 5: xxx

Can this be done? Is there any library I could use?

Comment: make different patterns using alternation in regex

Comment: @rock321987 could you please elaborate?

Comment: you should start reading regex..have you read regex?

Comment: I haven't done anything right now, just wanted to know how do I get started with it. And I know how to write the regex for each pattern. Need to know how to put it all together.

Comment: using alternation(OR), you can do it..It is denoted by `|`..i had written already though :- https://regex101.com/r/xU9nK1/2

Comment: Are you looking for https://regex101.com/r/qX6xT2/1

Comment: @Uchiha yours will also match `BC901`..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my above posting as i am still unable to add comment to a question.

hi innowqhy,

write 5 different regular expression matching 5 patterns that are given above
    function fieldsCheck(){

```
var re1=/AB\d\dTX\d\d$/;
var re2=/AB\d\dTXA\d\d$/;
var re3=/ABC\d{3}$/;
var re4=/A\d{3}$/;
var re5=/\d{3}$/;
var field= form.field.value;

if(re1.test(field) ||re2.test(field) ||re3.test(field) ||re4.test(field) ||re5.test(field) ){
alert("Test success");
return true;
}else{
alert("test failed");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
function validate($value){



    if(preg_match("/AB[\\w]{2}TX[\\w]{2}/", $value, $matches))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    elseif(preg_match("/AB[\\w]{2}TXA[\\w]{3}/", $value, $matches))
    {
        return 2;
    }
    elseif(preg_match("/ABC[\\w]{3}/", $value, $matches))
    {
        return 3;
    }
    elseif(preg_match("/A[\\w]{3}/", $value, $matches))
    {
        return 4;
    }
    elseif(preg_match("/[\\w]{3}/", $value, $matches))
    {
        return 5;
    }
    else
    {
        return 6;
    }

}


$str = "ABxxTXxx";
var_dump(validate($str));
```